# Connecting two computers with MIDI via a USB Host-Host cable?

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi, usb-3, midi

I am currently looking for a way to connect two computers with MIDI.

I need to connect my Raspberry Pi to my Linux desktop. Are you able to do that with a USB3 Host-to-Host cable? Or is there a different way? I've heard of RTPMidi, but it's USD$5, while I still have a host-to-host cable lying around.